# how does this simplify?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I am really stumped as to how it simplifies. I should know this, but it has been a very, very, long summer.

Comment: Have you tried dividing the numerator and denominator by $2$?

Comment: I am a bit sad that Austin has edited this post. I only upvoted it because the original rendering of the formula was so amusing.

Comment: It looked rather like it was written in lipstick on a white T-shirt.  Were you expecting it to simplify down to give some woman's phone number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pull out a factor of $2$ and cancel:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{4-2\sqrt{2}}{4} &= \frac{2(2 - \sqrt{2})}{2 \cdot 2}\\
&= \frac{2}{2}\cdot \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
&= 1 \cdot \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
&= \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

Notice we didn't do anything special with the $\sqrt{2}$; it may as well have just been an $x$.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot.